# how can i make php alert pop ups just like in javascript

Tags: php

i need a pop up window which asks me before proceeding to next like **alert** in **javascript**.

Is any built in facility in PHP like that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

PHP is a server-side language - you generate HTML/JS from it, the browser doesn't see PHP because it interprets the actual file PHP/server outputs.

You probably want the window.confirm method:

```
var continueOn = window.confirm('proceed?');

if ( continueOn ) {
    alert('go on');
} else {
    alert('exit');
}
```

Answer (score 2):

No, PHP is server side.

The best that you can do is to have PHP output HTML/JS that creates pop ups (whether they're floating divs, JS alerts, etc.).

Answer (score 1):

Considering PHP is executed on the server-side, you cannot have this kind of "pop-up" in PHP : you'll have to go with some Javascript code, that's executed on the client-side *(ie, in the user's browser)*.